# Decoding an Base64 encoded Array in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I want to decode and use an base64 encoded array in php my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$hash = "YXJyYXkoInNhbXBsZV9pZCI9PiJObnJ5amZCV0p0STllalNRcnE2NHZIejFjc084RnVqUHRGRGk5WkdtM0Z3Vm9ieHprOSIsICJ4eF94eF94eHhfeHh4MSI9PiIwIiwgInNhbXBsZTIiID0+IjAiKQ==";
$hash_decoded = base64_decode($hash);
$all_infos = $hash_decoded;

$sample_id = $all_infos['sample_id'];
$xx_xx_xxx_xxx1 = $all_infos['xx_xx_xxx_xxx1'];
$sample2 = $all_infos['sample2'];
echo $sample_id;     ?>
```

and the decoded array is

```
array("sample_id"=>"NnryjfBWJtI9ejSQrq64vHz1csO8FujPtFDi9ZGm3FwVobxzk9", "xx_xx_xxx_xxx1"=>"0", "sample2" =>"0")
```

I can´t get the infos from the Array. The Console says

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'sample_id' in [...] on line 6
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'xx_xx_xxx_xxx1' in [...] on line 7
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'sample2' in [...] on line 8
a
```

Where´s the problem? Thank´s for answers.

Comment: show all your code, not just what you believe is enough for us to guess what you did.

Comment: You're asking where's the problem.... I'm going to ask you **what's** the problem? You're pretty much saying that the base64 encoded data was decoded and you're even showing the result you got... and you're using it correctly. I don't know what's happening (or not happening) that makes you ask this question.

Comment: The way you have it right now, you need to `$all_infos = eval('return '.$hash_decoded);`, but this is a ***very bad idea***. Instead, save your array using `json_encode` in the first place, instead of `base64_encode`, and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Zeke Did you try running the code?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat the question did not have the errors when I commented on it. And no, I hadn’t, I just asked because nothing useful was there at the moment. Now there’s definitely more information.

Comment: @Zeke There was more information than required from the start :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat not from my point of view, especially because the question explicitly said and still says that the decoded array was an array, not a String. If that sentence hadn’t been written, then it was obvious from the beginning. But as far as I know “decoded array” means array, so I took that as a fact, not as an “I believe it is an array”. Also, `eval()` shouldn’t be used, as warned by php.net, and another solution should be found.

Comment: @Zeke `eval()` is completely safe when you know about it. I trust my coworkers to supply a valid code for it, and `eval()` will just work fine in that case. Also, `base64_decode()` always returns a string but I think that did not click. Anyways, this discussion would go on and on if we did not stop. Let's end it here :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat of course, you still need to be sure you’re doing things safely. Still, it should be avoided if possible. I know that the function returns a string, but you know that many askers only post parts of the code, omitting other parts. So if the asker says it was decoded, then I take that as part of the information. That’s why I commented here instead of answering for the sake of answering. I don’t like answering things when I’m not sure what’s going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$all_infos` variable is a string, since that is what you get back from `base64_decode($hash)`. You cannot then expect it to become an array having properties like `sample_id`.

This particular string has a PHP expression encoded, but you'll need to interpret that string. One way is to use the infamous `eval` function. Take care to only use it when you trust the source of that string!

```
eval('$all_infos = ' . $hash_decoded . ";");
```

Comment: You said i should only use it when i trust the source of the string but can i make the string safe when i use the stripslashes function?

Comment: You said i should only use this function when i trust the source of the string but can i make the string safe to use when i filter it with the `stripslashes ` function?

Comment: No, that is no guarantee and might even make the evaluation fail. The source should provide that data as JSON, which is safe to decode.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an older question, but none of the answers seem to be correct and definitely the eval() is not recommended to be used.

As far as I see, the main issue is that you're directly encoding the array with base64_encode that convert it to a string without serializing in the first place the array (which will solve your issue); so, make sure you're using PHP's function before:

```
 serialize ( mixed $value ) : string
```

Below is a fully working example for your case:

```
// Step 1: Correctly format the original array with serialize to not lose their type and structure
$originalArray = ["sample_id"=>"NnryjfBWJtI9ejSQrq64vHz1csO8FujPtFDi9ZGm3FwVobxzk9", "xx_xx_xxx_xxx1"=>"0", "sample2" =>"0"];
// first serialize the array and then base64_encode it
$hashedArray =  base64_encode(serialize($originalArray));
// output : YTozOntzOjk6InNhbXBsZV9pZCI7czo1MDoiTm5yeWpmQldKdEk5ZWpTUXJxNjR2SHoxY3NPOEZ1alB0RkRpOVpHbTNGd1ZvYnh6azkiO3M6MTQ6Inh4X3h4X3h4eF94eHgxIjtzOjE6IjAiO3M6Nzoic2FtcGxlMiI7czoxOiIwIjt9
print_r($hashedArray);


// Step 2: Re-decoding the hash to use the array
$hash = "YTozOntzOjk6InNhbXBsZV9pZCI7czo1MDoiTm5yeWpmQldKdEk5ZWpTUXJxNjR2SHoxY3NPOEZ1alB0RkRpOVpHbTNGd1ZvYnh6azkiO3M6MTQ6Inh4X3h4X3h4eF94eHgxIjtzOjE6IjAiO3M6Nzoic2FtcGxlMiI7czoxOiIwIjt9";
$hashDecoded = unserialize(base64_decode($hash));
//output : Array ( [sample_id] => NnryjfBWJtI9ejSQrq64vHz1csO8FujPtFDi9ZGm3FwVobxzk9 [xx_xx_xxx_xxx1] => 0 [sample2] => 0 ) 
print_r($hashDecoded);
// Getting the information you want:
$sample_id = $hashDecoded['sample_id'];
$xx_xx_xxx_xxx1 = $hashDecoded['xx_xx_xxx_xxx1'];
$sample2 = $hashDecoded['sample2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To decode base64 encoded elements of array use this PHP code:

```
$array = ["sample_id"=>"NnryjfBWJtI9ejSQrq64vHz1csO8FujPtFDi9ZGm3FwVobxzk9"];
array_walk($array, 'array_decode');
function array_decode(&$item) {
     $item = base64_decode($item);
}
```