# Accessing object from array returns undefined

Tags: php

Below is the print output from `$_POST['image']`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['filename'] => cn-100x100.png
            ['contents'] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['filename'] => 
            ['contents'] => 
        )

)
```

when I do,

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r((object)$_POST['image'][0]['filename']);
exit;
```

it gives me an error

> Notice:  Undefined index: filename

### Update

I tried to do `var_dump( (array)$_POST['image'])`,

> array(2) { ["'filename'"]=> string(14) "cn-100x100.png"
> ["'contents'"]=> string(10218) "base64..."}

If I removed the `base64` data from the array column `['contents']`, now I can access the first array.

Comment: i think there might be some issues in your array format

Comment: $array = array( 
            0 => [
               "filename" => 'cn-100x100.png',
               "contents" => ''
                
            ],
            
            1 =>[  
               "filename" => '',
               "contents" =>  ''
                
            ],
            
 
         );
print_r((object)$array[0]['filename']); this works

Comment: Theres a base64 data on the column  `contents` If I removed the `base64` data from the array column `['contents']`, now I can access the first array. Any ideas, help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599135/decoding-an-base64-encoded-array-in-php ,it is a similar  issue please refer

Answer (score 1):

you can update it

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r((array)$_POST['image'][0]['filename']);
exit;
```

Comment: Theres a base64 data on the column  `contents` If I removed the `base64` data from the array column `['contents']`, now I can access the first array. Any ideas, help?

Answer (score 1):

Object properties cannot be accessed by using `$object['property_name']`

You have to use the arrow syntax `$object->property_name` or `$object->{'property_name'}`

In this case it looks like somehow `$_POST['image']` has been defined as an object, so you would have to use:
`$_POST['image']->{'0'}['filename']`

You could also convert it to an array by using: `$_POST['image'] = (array)$_POST['image'];`

Comment: Theres a base64 data on the column  `contents` If I removed the `base64` data from the array column `['contents']`, now I can access the first array. Any ideas, help?

Comment: A bit of a hack, but consistent way to convert objects to array is by using: `$variable = json_decode(json_encode($variable),true);` - try applying this to `$_POST['image']` variable

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the object into the array by following way

```
$all_images= (array) $_POST['image'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($all_images);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now, you can access like this `$all_images[0]['filename']`